# How to get text of elements in carousel

Tags: testing, selenium-webdriver, carousel

How to get the text in the Strong tags. I my case User 1 and User 2. This is the HTML:

```
                <div id="socialVertCarPersIm" class="carousel slide">
                <div class="carousel-inner vertical">
                        <div class="item active">
                            <a href="#/finances/hr/4" target="_blank" class="socImage">
                                    <span style="background:url('http://en.mava-foundation.org/wp-content/uploads/2012/06/Maja-Hoffman_c-Philip-Bermingham-small.jpg') center center no-repeat"></span>
                            </a>
                            <a href="#/finances/hr/4" target="_blank" class="socPerson">
                                <p><strong>User 1</strong></p>
                                <p></p>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="item">
                            <a href="#/finances/hr/26" target="_blank" class="socImage">
                                    <span style="background:url('https://media.licdn.com/mpr/mpr/shrinknp_200_200/AAEAAQAAAAAAAAazAAAAJDFlZTZlZjFhLTFjYTktNDE1ZS04MDE0LWU0NmEzZTJiMjU4Mw.jpg') center center no-repeat"></span>
                            </a>
                            <a href="#/finances/hr/26" target="_blank" class="socPerson">
                                <p><strong>User 2</strong></p>
                                <p></p>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

I want to check the names with Assert.assertEquals. this is my code:

```
        List <WebElement> names = driver.findElements(By.xpath(".//*[@id='socialVertCarPersIm']//strong"));

        ArrayList list1 = new ArrayList();
        String name;

        for (int i = 0; i<names.size(); i++){
            int index = i+1;
            name = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='socialVertCarPersIm']//strong" + "[" + index + "]")).getText();
            list1.add(name);

            System.out.println(name);
        }
```

When I run my code nothing happens in the console and I want to get the names of User 1 and User 2 and compare them using Assert.assertEquals but don't know how to do it.

Comment: Where are you stuck? What is the error you are seeing? At which line? Thanks

Comment: When I run my code nothing happens in the console and I want to get the names of User 1 and User 2 and compare them using Assert.assertEquals but don't know how to do it.

Comment: If the URL is a public URL can you share it for further Analysis? Thanks

Comment: @DebanjanB sorry, but it is not public.